# An internal error occurred during: "Building UI model"

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i am trying to create new project in eclipse "Spring started Project" but it gives the error `An internal error occurred during: "Building UI model".
com/google/common/base/Function`

i am new in spring boot ..please solve the problem also shared screenshot [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmmai.jpg)

Comment: someone please help mi..

Answer (score 7):

Please install "TestNG plug-in for Eclipse". It will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem same you. Because your Eclipse and STS version miss match. example I use Eclipse Mar(4.5.x) and download Spring version 3.8.2  this is miss match version.

I have 2 solution

1. Download Spring Tool suit (STS) at "https://spring.io/tools/sts/legacy"
   Please check your Eclipse before download

OR

2. you can not download STS at "Eclipse Market Place". because eclipse search new version of STS. (is match for new vesion of Eclipse)
   you can download at "Install new software". and I use this Link http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.X/
   you can insert version match for your Eclipse at "x"

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue. I fixed it by updating all the plugins etc. You need to click on "Check for Updates" in help and proceed further.

I have Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3). I added STS plugin through Marketplace. (See http://www.adeveloperdiary.com/java/spring-boot/create-spring-boot-application-step-step/) 
After that I got the same error while creating new spring starter project.

```
An internal error occurred during: "Building UI model".
com/google/common/base/Function
```

After updating all the plugins i am able to creat a new spring starter project.

Regards,
Krishan

Answer (score 0):

Just check your spring tool suite configuration file and provide jdk path for vm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).